# MDL table retrieve data checked values

Tags: javascript, material-design, material-design-lite

I'm using tables of MDL lib. https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#tables-section­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

But there are no docs how I can retrieve checked values about.

I found only this solution, but this not helping at all:

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementById('team-table-id')
        .querySelector('tbody').querySelectorAll('.mdl-checkbox__input');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
            console.log(this)
            // returns <input type="checkbox" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
            // how can I assign and retrieve value to/from this input?
        });
    }
```

How can I assign a value to checkbox/input of table rows at all?

How can I retrieve single checked values?

How can I handle "select all" event and get data of all rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I didn't find solution.
So I make my own for temporary:

1) Assign some class for tr's, so it can be found when check event happend

2) assign value for tr's. It can be serialized values or smth like that

3) listen check event and get data

Markup:

```
<table id="team-table-id" width="100%" class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp">
        <thead>
        <tr class="row-info" data-value="all">
            <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Donation Invoice</th>
            <th>Donation Name</th>
            <th>Donation price</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="row-info" data-value="one more value">
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">I-20170419120440</td>
            <td>Some Donation Name</td>
            <td>$2.90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-info" data-value="another value">
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">C-20170419120454</td>
            <td>Anothre</td>
            <td>$1.25</td>
        </tr>
<!--etc...-->
```

Javascript:

```
window.findAncestor = (el, cls) => {
   while ((el = el.parentElement) && !el.classList.contains(cls));
        return el;
}


let checkboxes = document.getElementById('team-table-id')
        .querySelectorAll('.mdl-checkbox__input');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
            console.log(findAncestor(this, 'row-info'))
        });
// Returns parent table row, so you can get selected data. 
// For example <tr data-value="some value" class="row-info">....
```

Please, feel free to suggest right one.

**UPD:**
This approach dnt have bugs and can hanlde all checked values, so I've marked this as "solved".

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1210 where several solutions (work-around) are presented depending on the version of MDL

Answer (score 0):

I am following this (work-around)

On `window.onload` I am adding `onclick` attribute to all checkbox to  call function `getCheckValue(this)`, this function traverse through `dom` to get `innerHTML` of each `td` in `tr`

```
window.onload=function(){
    var checkAll=document.getElementsByClassName('mdl-checkbox__input') 
    for(var i=0;i<checkAll.length;i++){ 
        checkAll[i].setAttribute('onclick','getCheckValue(this)')   
    }
}

function getCheckValue(obj){

    if(obj.checked){
     /*th is checked in thead*/
       if(obj.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.nodeName=='THEAD'){
        var trs=obj.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.children
        for(var i=0;i<trs.length;i++){
            var tds=trs[i].getElementsByTagName('td')
                for(var j=1;j<tds.length;j++){
                    console.log(tds[j].innerHTML)
                }
            }
        }
        else{
           /*td inside tbody is checked*/
            var tds=obj.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('td')
            for(var i=1;i<tds.length;i++){
                console.log(tds[i].innerHTML)
            }
        }

    }else{
    /* uncheck th checkbox of thead*/
    if(obj.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.nodeName!='THEAD'){
    obj.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.classList.remove('is-checked')
    obj.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.checked=false
    }   

    }

}
```

[Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/QwTlQrxMxkm7qZ2e7j3O?p=preview) for demonstration